# Dojo 1.8: join list domConstruct.toDom

Tags: dojo

Hi I have problem joining two lists together before applying  domConstruct.toDom.

I understand that it can be done that way ie:,

```
    require(["dojo/text!, myListHtml.html", "dojo/domReady!"], 
    function(myListHtml){
     var list = domConstruct.toDom(myListHtml);
    });
```

However, i would like to know how two lists should be coded ie:-

```
require(["dojo/domReady!"], function(){
var list = domConstruct.toDom
('<ol>\
   <li class="odd">\
    <div class="bold">\
     <a class="odd">Odd</a>\
    </div>\
   </li>\
   <li class="even">\
    <div class="italic">\
     <a class="even">Even</a>\
    </div>\
   </li>\
  </ol>\

  <ol id="list2">\
   <li class="odd">Odd</li>\
  </ol>');
```

Please advise. Thanks in advance
Clement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you trying to join the two lists? domConstruct.toDom() returns a single domNode, but what you are trying above would be two domNodes.

If you really want to "combine" them, you can nest them inside another domNode, like this:

```
var lists = domConstruct.toDom(
'<div>\
   <ol>\
    <li class="odd">\
    ...
   </ol>\
   <ol id="list2">\
    <li class="odd">Odd</li>\
   </ol>\
 </div>');
```

If you want to "combine" them on the page, consider creating them separately and adding them to the page using domConstruct.place(), like this:

```
domConstruct.place('<ol>\
    <li class="odd">\
    ...
   </ol>', "idOfWhateverYouWantToContainIt");

domConstruct.place('<ol id="list2">\
    ...
   </ol>', "idOfWhateverYouWantToContainIt");
```

Comment: Hi Thanks I just wanna try another option though the first would be better,